# freenas disc problems - smart error - how to repair zfs raid?

Tags: freebsd, hard-drive, zfs, truenas, smartctl

My problem was that hdds of my zfs raid partly degraded and partly destroyed after a lightning.

I was able to detect the problem with zpool status:

```
zpool status myzfs
pool myzfs
state: DEGRADED (DESTROYED)
```

The good news. ZFS seems to be really reliable and I in my case was able to recover the raid fully. How I recovered see below in the answer.

## Recovering a ZFS Raid I learned two things:

1. **1 failed drive brings a zpool down**. An raid based on stiped mirrows however stays available. Details exlained in [ZFS: You should use mirror vdevs, not RAIDZ](http://jrs-s.net/2015/02/06/zfs-you-should-use-mirror-vdevs-not-raidz/)
2. Recovering and **resilvering a
   zpool based on raidz2-0 takes a really long time.** You may be better of with a striped mirror. This has pros and cons widely discussed in the [internet](http://jrs-s.net/2015/02/06/zfs-you-should-use-mirror-vdevs-not-raidz/) sdfg
3. **A raid is NOT a backup**! Offshoring backups into the cloud or a second location is an big advantage and is possible today without any big affords. Most Raids allow backups to the cloud or ZFS replication to another NAS

## Orignal debug information

*This however there not necessarily important to detect and solve the problem.*

I have troubles with my freenas 9.2.1. It crashed today. Its running a fileserver on zfs jbod raid 2. I'm not sure what exactly causes the problems. The system is booting however reacting pretty slow. From the logs I couldn't figure anything totally wrong. Thus I'm not sure where to get startet with error analysis and how to solve them.

The problem is that the system crashes and responds pretty slow. The freenas web interface crashes as well since pyhon dies.

Freenas is installed on an usb stick, an additional drive (2tb) is attached for backup. The other 4 drives run as zfs raid.

The harddrives do show smart errors. How can I fix them? May they be the reason for the problems.

TOP

```
CPU:  0.1% user,  0.0% nice,  2.5% system,  0.1% interrupt, 97.3% idle
Mem: 131M Active, 11G Inact, 3689M Wired, 494M Cache, 3232M Buf, 16M Free
ARC: 3028K Total, 347K MFU, 1858K MRU, 16K Anon, 330K Header, 477K Other
Swap: 10G Total, 636K Used, 10G Free
```

DF

```
Filesystem                       Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/ufs/FreeNASs2a              971M    866M     27M    97%    /
devfs                            1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/md0                         4.8M    3.5M    918k    79%    /etc
/dev/md1                         843k    2.6k    773k     0%    /mnt
/dev/md2                         156M     40M    103M    28%    /var
/dev/ufs/FreeNASs4                20M    3.4M     15M    18%    /data
fink-zfs01                       6.0T    249k    6.0T     0%    /mnt/fink-zfs01
fink-zfs01/.system               6.0T    249k    6.0T     0%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/.system
fink-zfs01/.system/cores         6.0T     14M    6.0T     0%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/.system/cores
fink-zfs01/.system/samba4        6.0T    862k    6.0T     0%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/.system/samba4
fink-zfs01/.system/syslog        6.0T    2.7M    6.0T     0%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/.system/syslog
fink-zfs01/shares                6.0T    261k    6.0T     0%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/shares
fink-zfs01/shares/fink-privat    6.4T    344G    6.0T     5%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/shares/fink-privat
fink-zfs01/shares/gf             6.0T    214k    6.0T     0%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/shares/gf
fink-zfs01/shares/kundendaten    6.6T    563G    6.0T     9%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/shares/kundendaten
fink-zfs01/shares/zubehoer       6.6T    539G    6.0T     8%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/shares/zubehoer
fink-zfs01/temp                  6.2T    106G    6.0T     2%    /mnt/fink-zfs01/temp
/dev/ufs/Backup                  1.9T    114G    1.7T     6%    /mnt/Backup
```

/var/log/messages

```
Jan 21 21:48:32 s-FreeNAS root: /etc/rc: WARNING: failed to start syslogd
Jan 21 21:48:32 s-FreeNAS kernel: .
Jan 21 21:48:32 s-FreeNAS root: /etc/rc: WARNING: failed to start watchdogd
Jan 21 21:48:32 s-FreeNAS root: /etc/rc: WARNING: failed precmd routine for vmware_guestd
Jan 21 21:48:34 s-FreeNAS ntpd[2589]: ntpd 4.2.4p5-a (1)
Jan 21 21:48:34 s-FreeNAS kernel: .
Jan 21 21:48:36 s-FreeNAS generate_smb4_conf.py: [common.pipesubr:58] Popen()ing: zfs list -H -o mountpoint,name
Jan 21 21:48:36 s-FreeNAS generate_smb4_conf.py: [common.pipesubr:58] Popen()ing: zfs list -H -o mountpoint
Jan 21 21:48:38 s-FreeNAS last message repeated 4 times
Jan 21 21:48:38 s-FreeNAS generate_smb4_conf.py: [common.pipesubr:58] Popen()ing: /usr/local/bin/pdbedit -d 0 -i smbpasswd:/tmp/tmpEKKZ2A -e tdbsam:/var/etc/private/passdb.tdb -s /usr/local/etc/smb4.conf
Jan 21 21:48:43 s-FreeNAS ntpd[2590]: time reset -0.194758 s
Jan 21 21:48:45 s-FreeNAS smartd[2867]: Device: /dev/ada3, FAILED SMART self-check. BACK UP DATA NOW!
Jan 21 21:48:45 s-FreeNAS smartd[2867]: Device: /dev/ada3, 164 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
Jan 21 21:48:45 s-FreeNAS smartd[2867]: Device: /dev/ada3, Failed SMART usage Attribute: 5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct.
Jan 21 21:48:45 s-FreeNAS smartd[2867]: Device: /dev/ada3, previous self-test completed with error (unknown test element)
Jan 21 21:48:51 s-FreeNAS mDNSResponder: mDNSResponder (Engineering Build) (Mar  1 2014 18:12:24) starting
Jan 21 21:48:51 s-FreeNAS mDNSResponder:   8: Listening for incoming Unix Domain Socket client requests
Jan 21 21:48:51 s-FreeNAS mDNSResponder: mDNS_AddDNSServer: Lock not held! mDNS_busy (0) mDNS_reentrancy (0)
Jan 21 21:48:51 s-FreeNAS mDNSResponder: mDNS_AddDNSServer: Lock not held! mDNS_busy (0) mDNS_reentrancy (0)
Jan 21 21:48:53 s-FreeNAS netatalk[3142]: Netatalk AFP server starting
Jan 21 21:48:53 s-FreeNAS cnid_metad[3179]: CNID Server listening on localhost:4700
Jan 21 21:48:53 s-FreeNAS kernel: done.
Jan 21 21:48:54 s-FreeNAS mDNSResponder: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 0000000800C2FD60 s-FreeNAS.local. (Addr) that's already in the list
...
Jan 21 21:48:54 s-FreeNAS mDNSResponder: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 0000000800C30180 109.1.1.10.in-addr.arpa. (PTR) that's already in the list

Jan 21 22:04:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: swap_pager: indefinite wait buffer: bufobj: 0, blkno: 1572950, size: 8192
...
Jan 21 22:05:25 s-FreeNAS kernel: GEOM_ELI: g_eli_read_done() failed ada0p1.eli[READ(offset=110592, length=4096)]
Jan 21 22:05:25 s-FreeNAS kernel: swap_pager: I/O error - pagein failed; blkno 1572894,size 4096, error 5
Jan 21 22:05:25 s-FreeNAS kernel: vm_fault: pager read error, pid 3020 (python2.7)
Jan 21 22:05:25 s-FreeNAS kernel: Failed to write core file for process python2.7 (error 14)
...
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): READ_FPDMA_QUEUED. ACB: 60 08 70 02 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): CAM status: ATA Status Error
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): ATA status: 41 (DRDY ERR), error: 40 (UNC )
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): RES: 41 40 70 02 00 40 00 00 00 00 00
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): Error 5, Retries exhausted
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: GEOM_ELI: g_eli_read_done() failed ada0p1.eli[READ(offset=253952, length=4096)]
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: swap_pager: I/O error - pagein failed; blkno 1572929,size 4096, error 5
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: vm_fault: pager read error, pid 2869 (smartd)
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: Failed to write core file for process smartd (error 14)
Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: pid 2869 (smartd), uid 0: exited on signal 11
```

smartctl --scan

```
/dev/ada0 -d atacam # /dev/ada0, ATA device
/dev/ada1 -d atacam # /dev/ada1, ATA device
/dev/ada2 -d atacam # /dev/ada2, ATA device
/dev/pass3 -d atacam # /dev/pass3, ATA device
/dev/ada3 -d atacam # /dev/ada3, ATA device
/dev/ada4 -d atacam # /dev/ada4, ATA device
/dev/ada5 -d atacam # /dev/ada5, ATA device
```

smartctl -a /dev/ada3

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p3 amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L0
Serial Number:    WD-WMC1F1211607
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 0ae5c0b4c
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jan 21 23:07:55 2015 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x85) Offline data collection activity
                    was aborted by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  73) The previous self-test completed having
                    a test element that failed and the test
                    element that failed is not known.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (41640) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:           (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:   (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:   ( 451) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:   (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x70bd) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   187   187   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       553
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   142   138   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       11900
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       93
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   139   139   140    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 1791
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       7553
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       93
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       59
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   108   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       44
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       353
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       162
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7553         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7552         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7551         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7550         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7549         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7548         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7547         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7546         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7545         -
#10  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7544         -
#11  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7543         -
#12  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      7542         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7541         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7540         -
#15  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      7538         1148054536
#16  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      7538         1148054536
#17  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      7536         1148057328
#18  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      7535         1148057328
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7530         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7529         -
#21  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      7528         1148057328

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:**

*Repairing a destroyed ZFS Pool and replacing degraded or unavailable process is dangerous. For me it worked. However read all documentations carefully and read about typical failures. Otherwise you may destroy your raid fully. You may'd like to contact a professional helping you recovering your data.*

However reading carefully you should be able to recover your zfs raid yourself!

### Situation

Further research showed that we had current peaks from an lightning which destroyed the hard drives and corrupted others. Thus the pool zfs pool was defect.

This can be detected using zpool status:

```
zpool status myzfs
pool myzfs
state: DEGRADED (DESTROYED)
```

### Recovering destroyed ZFS Storage Pool

This problem may be (at least for me) be solved through:

```
zpool destroy myzfs
zpool import -Df       # this made the zpool accessible again
```

zpool however continued to be degraded in reason of 1 drive being fully destroyed.

Full documentation on recovering destroyed zfs pools see oracle documentation on [recovering destroyed zfs storage pools](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/6n7ht6r0o/index.html)

### Replacing degraded ZFS drive

Recovering the degraded zpool did not fully solve the problem since it still had degraded/defect drives

zpool -status myzfs
config:

```
    NAME         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    myzfs        DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz2-0   DEGRADED     0     0     0
        gptid/uuid1       ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/uuid2       ONLINE       0     0     0
        gptid/uuid3       ONLINE       0     0     0
        778923478919345   UNAVAIL      0     0     0  /was /dev/ada4
```

Drive replacement is also documented very well in the internet. However It depends a little bit if you are using a hotspare or not, the raid level, ...

Basically it worked for me pretty simple though

```
zpool replace myzfs 778923478919345
```

The replacement is also documented very well by oracle under [Replacing a Device in a ZFS Storage Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcet/)

Answer (score 2):

> FreeBSD crashes because of this error:
>
> an 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0):
>   READ_FPDMA_QUEUED. ACB: 60 08 70 02 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 Jan 21
>   22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): CAM status: ATA
>   Status Error Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0):
>   ATA status: 41 (DRDY ERR), error: 40 (UNC ) Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS
>   kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): RES: 41 40 70 02 00 40 00 00 00 00 00
>   Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: (ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): Error 5,
>   Retries exhausted Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: GEOM_ELI:
>   g_eli_read_done() failed ada0p1.eli[READ(offset=253952, length=4096)]
>   Jan 21 22:19:44 s-FreeNAS kernel: swap_pager: I/O error - pagein
>   failed; blkno 1572929,size 4096, error 5

This means either a bad SATA cable, or - given you have another dying disk, ada3 - might suggest a power supply problem.  It's a system disk or a swap space, and because it's just plain UFS, with no redundancy, there is no way for the system to cope with this.

As for ZFS - please post `zpool status` output.

Comment: thx for your help, somehow oversaw your answer but found out myself that the zpool was degraded. I luckily was able to recover my zfs zpool. Going with zpool status and than recovering was the right way.